# Total spaces of orientable $2n$-sphere bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

If $\pi:E\to M$ is an orientable $S^{2n}$-bundle, then (see Bott-Tu 11.20) $$(1) \qquad \qquad H^{\ast}(E)=H^{\ast}(M) \otimes H^{\ast}(S^{2n}).$$ If $\pi:E'\to M'$ is another orientable $S^{2n}$-bundle such that $H^{\ast}(M')=H^{\ast}(M)$, then we conclude that from $(1)$ that $H^{\ast}(E)=H^{\ast}(E')$.

**Question:** Suppose that we further assume that $M$ and $M'$ are homeomorphic. What can we conclude about the topology of $E$ and $E'$ in this case? For example, is it true that $E$ and $E'$ are homotopy equivalent, or even homeomorphic? If this is too ambitious, what if we restrict to the case where $M$ and $M'$ are themselves homeomorphic to a sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the two $S^{2}$-bundles over $S^{2}$, $X_{2} = Bl_{p}(\mathbb{CP}^{2}) (= \mathbb{CP}^{2} \# \bar{\mathbb{CP}^{2}})$ and $X_{1} = S^{2} \times S^{2}$. Then the intersection form on $H^{2}(X_{i},\mathbb{Z})$ is even for $i=1$ and odd for $i=2$. Hence these 4-manifolds are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$ and $S^{4} \times S^{2}$ is another nice example

Answer (score 1):

Any $S^k$ bundle over $S^n$ can be trivialised over both hemispheres. Using this idea one sees that topologically, such bundles are classified by the gluing map over the equator, up to homotopy, which is an element of $$\pi_{n-1}(SO(k+1))$$

So for instance, from the fact that $\pi_1(SO(3))$ is not trivial, you can derive two non-equivalent $S^2$ bundles over $S^2$.

See also Norman Steenrod's *The Topology of Fibre Bundles*, Section 'The fibering of spheres by spheres'.

Comment: I conclude from your answer that, up to homotopy, there are exactly 2 distinct $S^2$ bundles over $S^2$, since $\pi_1(SO(3))=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Analagously, since $\pi_3(SO(3))=\mathbb{Z}$, there are, up to homotopy, infinitely many distinct $S^2$ bundles over $S^4$. @Nick L. has given two of these. Is this reasoning correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rpf Yes this is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question: From your answer it seems that an element of $\pi_{n-1}(SO(k+1))$ only determines the homotopy type of the (total space of the) bundle, but not the homeomorphism type? Why is this so?

Comment: @rpf What I meant here is that only the homotopy class of the gluing map is significant. But it entirely determines the bundle up to bundle equivalence.

Comment: Another question: if two $S^k$ bundles $\pi,\pi':E\to S^n$ over $S^n$ have homeomorphic total spaces, are the maps $\pi$ and $\pi'$ homotopic? Do they correspond to the same element of $\pi_{n-1}(SO(k+1))$?

Comment: @rpf: No, two different sphere bundles can have homeomorphic total spaces. That's how Milnor constructed exotic 7-spheres, by exhibiting them as $S^3$-bundles over $S^4$.